# Apply Escape Characters in Redirected Output

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, escape-characters

I'm running a program that prints lots of escape characters (like "Esc[1A", to move the cursor up one line), and trying to redirect the output to a log file. When I run the program without redirection, the final output looks something like this:

```
256 lines processed.
```

But when I redirect to a log file, this is what the file ends up looking like:

```
Processing line 1...
Esc[1AProcessing line 2...
Esc[1AProcessing line 3...
...
Esc[1AProcessing line 256...
Esc[1A256 lines processed.
```

What's happening is that on the terminal, the "Esc[1A" character is telling the cursor to back up, so that each successive line overwrites the last line, and in the end, only the last line is displayed.

I want to have the log file appear exactly as the final output of the program would appear without redirection. I know it's possible to pipe the output to `col -bp` in order to filter out the escape characters, but I'd like to actually *apply* them, so that my log files don't end up containing thousands of extraneous lines. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear those escapes as you read them - do what the terminal does and overwrite them.

This emulates the output you describe w/ `seq`:

```
seq -s "
$(printf '\033[A')" 10
```

If it writes out to a terminal which interprets that escape it will appear to print only `10`. But as you note in the question, it's really printing all of those numbers over one another. However, if I filter its output with `sed` like:

```
seq -s "
$(printf '\033[A')" 10 |
sed -e :n -e "\$!N;s/.*$(printf '\033\[A')//;tn"
```

...it *really* does print only `10` because `sed` continually reads in each next line of input and `s///`ubstitutes away everything from the head of pattern space to the last occurring *key up* escape. And each time it does so successfully, it branches back to the `:n` label to `t`ry again.

Comment: That's a decent solution but it would be nice if there was a solution that handled all escape characters without having to manually handle each one.